# How to use debounce inside custom validator in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using a custom validator in a form group, I am making an API call for every keyup and make validation based on the response. Now I want to use debounce to reduce the number of API calls, I have tried multiple ways but couldn't able to find make it.

This is my code.

```
 this.staggingBuckets = this.formBuilder.group({
  zeppelinSources: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({
    sourceType: ['', Validators.required],
    sourceName: ['', Validators.required]
  })]),
  zeppelinTargets: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.group({
    targetType: ['', Validators.required],
    targetName: ['', Validators.required, this.nodeNameValidator.bind(this)]
  })]),
  bucketName: ['', Validators.required],
  mode: ['', Validators.required],
  comments: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

This is my custom validator

```
 nodeNameValidator(control: FormControl) {
const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  if (control.value != "") {
    if (control.parent.controls['targetType'].value == "") {
      resolve({ 'message': "please select target type" });
      return null;
    }
    let targetType = control.parent.controls['targetType'].value.toLowerCase();
    let targetNodeTypeId = Constants.fetchNodeByNameType(targetType, 'data')['nodeTypeId'];
    let reqBody =
    {
      "name": control.value,
      "nodeTypeId": targetNodeTypeId
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataIngestion.validateTableName(reqBody).toPromise().then((res) => {
        if (res['statusType'].toLowerCase() == "info") {
          resolve(null);
        }
        else if (res['statusType'].toLowerCase() == "error") {
          resolve({ 'message': res['statusMessage'] });
        }
      })
    }, 1500)
  }
})
return promise
}
```

I am using setTimeout() here but this is just delaying the API call, but I want to use reduce the API calls, any suggestions might be helpful for me.

Comment: you have in angular custom ASYNC validator

Comment: yes @YosiLeibman I am trying to make an API call inside ASYNC validator, everything is working fine, I just need to reduce the API calls

Answer (score 0):

Can you try implementing RxJs? https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-ways-to-debounce-http-requests-in-angular-c407eb165ada?gi=dd13d0ad9cbe